# vscode-spotify NO_ACTIVE_DEVICE

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed vscode-spotify but I had this problem, if you have a little idea

> vscode-spotify: Failed to perform operation Unknown error: status
>   code404 ; { "error" : { "status" : 404, "message" : "Player command
>   failed: No active device found", "reason" : "NO_ACTIVE_DEVICE" } }

Comment: You should file an issue against that extension: https://github.com/ShyykoSerhiy/vscode-spotify/issues

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by Norsten in this Github [issue](https://github.com/ShyykoSerhiy/vscode-spotify/issues/76)

You should first play a song from any devices (Desktop app, web client, etc)

Then you'll be able to control it using the VSCode extension.

I know in an ideal world we would like to do everything directly through the extension and I believe they're working on it.

Comment: And when I close the web player, vscode-spotify stops working too. Indeed, that's not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and a workaround this issue is sending the device id with the play request URL. The problem is when sending request to the API it does not find any active device and hence the error, which is bad because if a device is asking a call then it is active and the API should understand that.

When from another spotify client the current device is selected and song is played, it works because  the current device id active status is set true. You can do the same with your request. Just give the device id as the current device it, which will set it to active and will play the song.

**https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play?device_id="+this._device_id**
Worked for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: So that your answer becomes useful you should also explain where this device_id comes from.